Replacing the backend causes changes in the behavior of the frontend
I replaced Node.js (Express) code with Rust (Actix Web) code. It caused a subtle change in the state of the frontend page. If unauthorized users access /login page, it redirects to a / page that allows access only to authenticated users.
The issue occurred because the backend was changed from Node.js to Rust. The frontend source code has not been modified at all.
In the API, I implemented a check to determine if the request contains a JWT token and whether the token is valid, returning a boolean value. The frontend uses the response to manage the state with setLoggedIn, but the problematic behavior was not resolved.
Node.js
// login status
export const userLoginStatus = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Not authorized, please login!" });
  }
  // verify the token
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

  if (decoded) {
    res.status(200).json(true);
  } else {
    res.status(401).json(false);
  }
});

Rust
pub async fn login_status(
    req: HttpRequest,
) -> impl Responder {
    match jwt::verify(&req) {
        Ok(_claims) => {
            success_log!("[user_handler] - [login_status] message: Authorized!");
            HttpResponse::Ok().json(true)
        },
        Err(_) => {
            error_log!("[user_handler] - [login_status] Not authorized");
            HttpResponse::Unauthorized().json(false)
        }
    }
}

pub fn verify <R: RequestHeaders>(req: &R)  -> Result<Claims, String> {
    // Extract a token from request header
    if let Some(auth_header) = req.get_headers().get("Authorization") {
        if let Ok(auth_str) = auth_header.to_str() {
            let parts: Vec<&str> = auth_str.split_whitespace().collect();
            if parts.len() == 2 && parts[0] == "Bearer" {
                let token = parts[1];
                // decode uesr info
                match decode_token(token) {
                    Ok(user_info) => {
                        return Ok(user_info.claims);
                    },
                    Err(error) => {
                        error_log!("[jwt] - [verify] error = {}", error);
                        return Err(error.to_string());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Err(AUTH_MSG.get("TOKEN_NOT_FOUND_IN_REQUEST_HEADER_MSG").unwrap_or(&"").to_string());
}

use jsonwebtoken::{encode, decode, Header, Algorithm, EncodingKey, DecodingKey, Validation, TokenData};

/// JWT Claims
///
/// * `id`  - ID.
/// * `sub` - email
/// * `exp` - expiration
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Claims {
    pub id: i32,
    pub sub: String,
    pub exp: usize,
}

pub trait RequestHeaders {
    fn get_headers(&self) -> &HeaderMap;
}

impl RequestHeaders for HttpRequest {
    fn get_headers(&self) -> &HeaderMap {
        self.headers()
    }
}

impl RequestHeaders for ServiceRequest {
    fn get_headers(&self) -> &HeaderMap {
        self.headers()
    }
}

pub fn create_token(email: &str, id: &i32) -> Result<String, jsonwebtoken::errors::Error> {

    // token due date 10 days
    let days = 60 * 60 * 24 * 10;

    let expiration = SystemTime::now() + Duration::from_secs(days);
    let claims = Claims {
        id: id.to_owned(),
        sub: email.to_owned(),
        exp: expiration.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs() as usize,
    };

    encode(
        &Header::default(),
        &claims,
        &EncodingKey::from_secret("secret".as_ref())
    )
}

pub fn decode_token(token: &str) -> Result<TokenData<Claims>, jsonwebtoken::errors::Error> {
    decode::<Claims>(
        token,
        &DecodingKey::from_secret("secret".as_ref()),
        &Validation::new(Algorithm::HS256)
    )
}


It's hard to know what it could be as the issue might be differences in e.g. headers from the middleware or token verification divergences, and there is no debug info. You should try to do differential testing: send the same request to both backends (either by doing both in the frontend or by adding an intermediate proxy "forking" the request) then compare the responses.

What is decode_token? Is it verifying the token's signature?

@kmdreko I added additional codes. And Yes, decode_token verifys token's signature

None of the code you've posted does any redirection, so we can't tell you why this occurs. We don't even really known what is happening if you don't show us.
